# How to get all controllers and request-mapping methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In my Application, I wanted to list down all of my controllers and request method. Can anybody tell how can I detect the controller annotation in the application?

Comment: You just need to look up for all classes annotated as `@Controller`|`@RestController` and methods annotated with `@RequestMapping`. But you should show some example of what specifically you're trying to achieve in order to give some more useful info. If you could provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that would be good enough.

Comment: I want to achieve it by programmatically Is there any handler that detects the controller classes and then looks up into the methods in spring.

Answer (score 2):

You could get a starting point by:

**1)** Injecting

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
```

**2)** Using

```
String[] getBeanNamesForType(@Nullable
                             Class<?> type)
```

If your controllers all extend a common base.

**3)** Use the

```
String[] getBeanDefinitionNames()
```

And then filter the ones ending in Controller.. if that is your common suffix for these.

For the methods themselves, you would most likely need to use reflection once you have the qualified controller class names.